# Grafana Dashboard - cannot view data (Failed to fetch)

Tags: java, server, statistics, grafana, influxdb

I'm currently working on Grafana Server with InfluxDB data. I send these data via Java application through InfluxDB and in Grafana I use queries to show data in panels. The problem is that when I'm trying to show data - it says "failed to fetch" error.

[image: This is how it looks like]

The weird thing with this is that when I change datasource to other data source (i.e. default) and then again to influxdb datasource, it shows data! Query works and panels show graphs. When I refresh the page or change timeline, I don't know why, but the error occurs again. It again says "failed to fetch". And again, when I try to change data source to different and back to influx, it works.. for a while until I refresh the page..